# How can I edit geo nodes to achieve this?

Tags: geometry-nodes

The final result should look like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMLT_s9nSnk):
[image]

I changed the settings in the modifiers tab to select my text object instead of the default object. I did that in 3 places in the modifiers tab. But I couldn't achieve the result.

I uploaded the original file and the file that I edited.

https://filebin.net/iegbgcqkeiezxlof

Comment: unfortunately google says your file is not safe and warns to download it...

Comment: @Chris It's a .blend file (not exe). You should trust me more than google haha. Should I upload it again on another website?

Comment: if possible, yes please

Comment: Here: https://easyupload.io/m/rsjx5z

Comment: ok, thank you, but even the original file you provided does not work...so maybe you should look for an original file which works?! Or does it work for you? if yes, which Blender version r u using?

Comment: @Chris It should work on the expermimental version 3.0

Comment: @Chris This is the tutorial that I'm trying to follow but he doesn't explain anything hahah: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KmrPR10OtZA

Comment: @Chris I got the original file from this website. You set the price to 0 and then you can download it. Here: https://blenderthings.gumroad.com/l/GroowyGeoNodes

Comment: even if i download that, i got errors like this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3JXo.png -> rot2 is not defined....so maybe the source is not that good.... and yes, i am on experimental version 3.0 from a few days ago

Comment: @Chris Okay I don't want to bother you too much. Thanks anyway for your trials to help me. I'll try to search for alternatives with completely different style haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a **Base Object** you want to apply the effect to
2. Duplicate it: the copy will become the plant once all the modifiers are in place, so we can call it **Plant Object**
3. On the **Plant Object** add the three vertex groups seen on the original plant object ("P", "POF", "PO"). Make sure each group has all vertices assigned
4. Select your Plant Object, then the original one and copy modifiers (Ctrl+L)
5. Duplicate the Empty Sphere object to use it as your **Plant Controller**
6. On your **Plant Object**, edit the modifiers: in the VertexWeightProximity modifiers, replace the target object with your **Plant Controller**. In the Shrinkwrap modifiers, replace the target with your **Base Object**

Now it should work correctly, except that the plant will react only to the Plant Controller's position and not the scale. To make also the scale work, you need to copy the drivers from the original plant object's VertexWeightProximity modifiers.

Comment: Thank you so much I'll try this and get back to you